# couldn't execute "ssh": no such file or directory

Tags: docker, ssh, containers, expect, spawn

I am trying to use a expect script in order to ssh from my container to an external device. I am using docker and CentOS is installed on that container.

The script is simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 60
set cmd "ssh edi@192.168.0.249"
#spawn {*}$cmd
spawn ssh edi@192.168.0.249
set timeout 30
expect "yes/no" {
        send "yes\r"
        expect "*?assword" { send "admin\r" }
        } "*?assword" { send "admin\r" }

expect "$ " { send "mkdir TEST1\r" }
interact
```

But everytime I try to run I run into this error:

```
[root@cacti]# expect test.expect 
spawn ssh edi@192.168.0.249
couldn't execute "ssh": no such file or directory
    while executing
"spawn ssh edi@192.168.0.249"
    (file "test.expect" line 9)

[root@cacti]# expect -c "spawn ssh 192.168.0.249"
spawn ssh 192.168.0.249
couldn't execute "ssh": no such file or directory
    while executing
"spawn ssh 192.168.0.249"
```

I even tried calling the expect script from a bash script and the results are the same. Please help me as I cannot find anything regarding this.

Comment: Is ssh installed? `sudo yum install openssh-clients`

Comment: A Docker image usually has a fairly minimal set of tools installed in it, so to @Yarin_007's comment, it probably does not contain a `/usr/bin/ssh` binary unless you've installed it in the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

As you've pointed out ssh was not installed and yum is not working. I've found an workaround by installing rpms which I've transferred to the container manually.

openssh-8.0p1-5.el8.src.rpm
openssh-8.0p1-5.el8.x86_64.rpm
openssh-clients-8.0p1-5.el8.x86_64.rpm
sshpass-1.06-8.el8.x86_64.rpm

rpm -i to install them.